# NodeJS MySQL INSERT and then immediately SELECT that data (SELECT does not always return results)

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I am struggling with an incredibly weird issue with a function.

Here is the code that inserts the data:

```
const pi = async () => {
return new Promise((resolve) => {
  db.query(
    "SELECT classID FROM pacesetterIndex WHERE classID = ?",
    [classID],
    function (err, result) {
      if (err) {
        res.status(500).send("Something went wrong");
      }

      if (result.length !== 0) {
        res.status(409).send("A pacesetter for this class already exists.");
      } else {
        let parentArr = [
          {
            classID: classID,
            teacherID: teacherID,
            subjectID: subjectID,
            pacesetterList: pacesetterList,
            createdAt: createdAt,
          },
        ];

        let newArr = [];
        parentArr.forEach((parent) => {
          parent.pacesetterList.forEach((child) => {
            newArr.push({
              classID: parent.classID,
              teacherID: parent.teacherID,
              subjectID: parent.subjectID,
              startDate: child.startDate,
              endDate: child.endDate,
              objectives: child.objectives,
              createdAt: parent.createdAt,
            });
          });
        });
        newArr.forEach((data) => {
          db.query(
            "INSERT INTO pacesetterIndex SET classID = ?, teacherID = ?, subjectID = ?, startDate = ?, endDate = ?, objectives = ?, createdAt = ?;",
            [
              data.classID,
              data.teacherID,
              data.subjectID,
              data.startDate,
              data.endDate,
              data.objectives,
              data.createdAt,
            ]
          );
        });
        resolve();
      }
    }
  );
});
```

Here is the code that selects the data:

```js
const insert = async () => {
try {
  const q1 = () => {
    return new Promise((res, rej) => {
      db.query(
        "SELECT studentID, classID FROM classStudent WHERE classID = ?;",
        [classID],
        (err, row) => {
          if (err) {
            return rej(err);
          } else {
            res(row);
          }
        }
      );
    });
  };
  const q2 = () => {
    return new Promise((res, rej) => {
      db.query(
        "SELECT pacesetterID FROM pacesetterIndex WHERE classID = ?;",
        [classID],
        (err, row) => {
          if (err) {
            return rej(err);
          } else {
            res(row);
          }
        }
      );
    });
  };

  const arr1 = await q1();
  const arr2 = await q2();
  let arr3 = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < arr2.length; j++) {
      arr3.push({ ...arr2[j], ...arr1[i] });
    }
  }

  console.log("Array 1", arr1.length);
  console.log("Array 2", arr2.length);
  console.log("Array 3", arr3.length);

  arr3.forEach((data) => {
    db.query(
      "INSERT INTO pacesetterEntries SET pacesetterID = ?, classID = ?, studentID = ?;",
      [data.pacesetterID, data.classID, data.studentID]
    );
  });
} catch (err) {
  console.log(err);
}
  };
```

And then both functions are called like this:

```
async function main() {
await pi();
await insert();
}
main();
```

This function contains 3 MySQL queries, 2 SELECT queries and 1 INSERT query. The first SELECT query (SELECT studentID, classID...) works every single time. But the second SELECT query (SELECT pacesetterID FROM....) only works the first time after the API starts. Or, pretty much whenever it feels like it.

The problem here is that the third and final query (INSERT INTO pacesetterEntries SET...) does not run if the second query returns now rows.

I have never come across anything like this before, if anyone has any ideas whatsoever I would be incredibly grateful.

As you can see I console.log as much as I can to see if the correct data is being passed through as the function runs. Query 2's console.log(res.length) contains a value maybe 10% of all the times this function is called.

I’m wondering if it is mysql2 that may be causing the issues with returning results for q2, it doesn’t seem to enjoy working with promises. But then again, my code may be poor. I would like to avoid using timeout at all costs, I’d like the function to run as it should - call one query and then move on to the next.

Please let me know if I can supply any more code.  *Note, I am using mysql2 and a connection pool to perform the db calls*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it with a setTimeout in the first function - pi().

```
const pi = async () => {
return new Promise((resolve) => {
  db.query(
    "SELECT classID FROM pacesetterIndex WHERE classID = ?",
    [classID],
    function (err, result) {
      if (err) {
        res.status(500).send("Something went wrong");
      }

      if (result.length !== 0) {
        res.status(409).send("A pacesetter for this class already exists.");
      } else {
        let parentArr = [
          {
            classID: classID,
            teacherID: teacherID,
            subjectID: subjectID,
            pacesetterList: pacesetterList,
            createdAt: createdAt,
          },
        ];

        let newArr = [];
        parentArr.forEach((parent) => {
          parent.pacesetterList.forEach((child) => {
            newArr.push({
              classID: parent.classID,
              teacherID: parent.teacherID,
              subjectID: parent.subjectID,
              startDate: child.startDate,
              endDate: child.endDate,
              objectives: child.objectives,
              createdAt: parent.createdAt,
            });
          });
        });
        newArr.forEach((data) => {
          db.query(
            "INSERT INTO pacesetterIndex SET classID = ?, teacherID = ?, subjectID = ?, startDate = ?, endDate = ?, objectives = ?, createdAt = ?;",
            [
              data.classID,
              data.teacherID,
              data.subjectID,
              data.startDate,
              data.endDate,
              data.objectives,
              data.createdAt,
            ]
          );
        });
        setTimeout(resolve, 500); <-- Made all my problems disappear
      }
    }
  );
});
};
```

My only concern is, pi() will require different amounts if time based on how much data is being passed to the function and the server hardware . If the setTimeout isn't long enough, the function won't finish before insert() decides it's tired of waiting and then fires. Any ideas on how to prevent this?